# .htaccess rule that only accepts a specific value in a list

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to accept this url structure, where `$level` can only be one of these values: `a-, a+, b-, b+, ab-, ab+`

```
domain.com/notes/a-
domain.com/notes/a+
domain.com/notes/b-
domain.com/notes/b+
domain.com/notes/ab-
domain.com/notes/ab+
```

I tried this approach, but I was unsuccessful.

```
RewriteRule ^notes/([a|o|b|ab]-+)$ /notes.php?level=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there, but `+` is a special character so it has to be escaped, and alternation (pipe character) goes in parentheses. I removed 'o' that wasn't in your list. `(?:)` just says don't capture this.

```
RewriteRule ^notes/((?:a|b|ab)(?:-|\+))$ notes.php?level=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)